# Fetch an Unread email from a particular address in outlook with VB Script

Tags: vbscript, outlook

I want to get the email address of the unread mail which is from a particular sender.i tried the following code but it did'nt work

```
Set olApp=CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olMAPI=olApp.GetNameSpace("MAPI") 
Set oFolder = olMAPI.GetDefaultFolder(6)
Set allEmails = oFolder.Items

For Each email In oFolder.Items


If email.Unread = True Then
If email.SenderEmailAddress="Kalyanam.Raghuram@xxxx.com" Then

MsgBox email.Subject


End If
End If
Next
```

so i checked what actually 'email.SenderEmailAddress' is verifying with then by inserting this code

```
For Each email In oFolder.Items

If email.Unread = True Then

MsgBox email.Subject
MsgBox email.SenderEmailAddress


End If
Next
```

it gave me some output which cannot be understood but readable.Please let me know any solution for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dio you mean you got back an EX type address instead of the expected SMTP?

Have you looked at the _ExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress?
In your case you can use MailItem.Sender.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress. Be prepared to handle nulls as each value can be null.

Comment: Thanks :) you were right,it was EX type address.your solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted worked for me, I am on Windows Vista with Outlook 2007

One thing I would change is this

```
        If LCase(email.SenderEmailAddress) = LCase("Kalyanam.Raghuram@xxxx.com") Then
          wscript.echo email.Subject
        End If
```